# C# AspNet Identity Web forms

Tags: c#, webforms, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-5

I had an ASP Net web forms application with database using Database First Approach. I then merged Aspnet Identity Tables into my existing db. Then i used Entity Framework Reverse Enigneer extension to convert to Code First.

1. I got the Code First POCO classes & mappings for My existing db. However for Aspnet identity i got only one file i.e. IdentityModels.cs. NO Code First Model classes....   IS IT RIGHT ? Should i have got those POCO classes for AspNet identity tables as well ??
2. I also want to refer to User Id of the AspNetUsers table into my db tables...Since there are no POCO classes... How to refer to them ???
3. Further, There are now two contexts.. a) ApplicationDbContext derived from IdentityDbContext. b) MydbContext.... How to unify them if possible ???
   Things seem scattered.

Not much documentation by Microsoft or otherwise...or the framework has become obsolete ????

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Official documentation is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/identity/ and the framework is not obsolete yet.

Comment: Thanks...went through the docs...but didnt get anything related my issues.

Answer (score 0):

It seems WebForms have been ditched starting VS 2017 & .NET Core.

Its time to move on to Razor Pages or MVC.

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 still supports webforms. And this really doesn't qualify as an answer--it should be a comment.